# Problema ao chamar classe dentro do Switch

Tags: java, switch

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto da facul que é um sistema básico para clinicas. Depois que o usuário logar, ele escolhera uma opção no menu onde será chamada a classe responsável. O problema que quando escolho qualquer opção do menu ele volta a pedir o login do usuário e não chama a classe correspondente a função..

```
public void telaLogin(){
    int cont = 0;
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
    System.out.println("------- Bem Vindo ao Sis-Clinica ------");
    System.out.println("   - LOGIN - ");
    do{
        System.out.print("Login: ");
        usuario = ler.next();
        System.out.print("\nSenha: ");
        senha = ler.next();

        if(usuario.equals("admin")&& (senha.equals("12345"))){
            System.out.println("Acesso confirmado!");
            Inicio();
        }else{
            System.out.println("Acesso negado!"+'\n'+"---- Digite novamente ----"+'\n');
            cont++;
        if(cont == 3){
            System.out.println("Sitema bloqueando. "+'\n'+"Encerrando!!!");
            System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }while(cont <= 3);       
}

public void Inicio(){
    int opcoes;
    System.out.println("$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$");
    System.out.println("------- Bem Vindo ao Sis-Clinica ------");
    System.out.println("   - INICIO - ");

    System.out.println(" 1 - NOVO ATENDIMENTO");
    System.out.println(" 2 - CONSULTAR PACIENTE");
    System.out.println(" 3 - EDITAR CADASTRO");
    System.out.println(" 4 - ENVIAR CONSULTA");
    System.out.println(" 5 - NOTIFICAR O PACIENTE");
    System.out.println(" 6 - SAIR");
    System.out.println("Escolha: ");
    opcoes = ler.nextInt();

    switch(opcoes){
        case 1:
            Cadastrar cad = new Cadastrar();
            break;
        case 2:
            Consultar cons = new Consultar();
            break;
        case 3:
            Editar edt = new Editar();
            break;
        case 4:
            Enviar env = new Enviar();
            break;
        case 5:
            Notificar not = new Notificar();
            break;
        case 6:
            System.out.println("Encerrando!!!");
            System.exit(0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Classe

```
public class Cadastrar {

    Scanner ler = new Scanner(System.in);
    String nomeArq="Relatorio.pdf";
    String nome;
    String ender;
    String email;
    String tel;
    String bairro;
    String numero;
    String exame;

    public void Inserir(){
    File arquivo; 
    System.out.printf("Nome completo do paciente: ");
    nome = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Endereço: ");
    ender = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Bairro: ");
    bairro = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Número: ");
    numero = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Telefone: ");
    tel = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("E-mail: ");
    email = ler.nextLine();
    System.out.printf("Exame: ");
    exame = ler.nextLine();

    nomeArq = nome +".txt";

    try
    {
      Formatter saida = new Formatter(nomeArq);
      saida.format("          --- Ficha cadastral de pacientes ---");
      saida.format("\n Nome do paciente: "+nome+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Endereço: "+ender+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Bairro: "+bairro+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Numero: "+numero+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Email: "+email+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Telefone: "+tel+"\n");
      saida.format("\n Exame: "+exame+"\n");
      saida.close();
        System.out.println("Arquivo '"+nomeArq+"' Salvo com sucesso!");
    }
    //mostrando erro em caso se nao for possivel gerar arquivo
    catch(Exception erro){
      System.out.println("Arquivo nao pode ser gerado!");
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Veja seu case esta usando o valor string ou inteiro. Verifique.

Comment: Atualizei ai galera

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é porquê você não está **parando o while**

```
if(usuario.equals("admin")&& (senha.equals("12345"))){
            System.out.println("Acesso confirmado!");
            Inicio();
            break;//impede que o while seja executado novamente
        }
```

Comment: Nesse caso ele ta saindo do laço.. mas nao ta chamando as classes, pq logo ele para de executar.

Comment: deixa eu ver se entendi, apos escolher a opção 1 para de executar? se for isto você pode chamar o método novamente  Cadastrar cad = new Cadastrar(); inicio(); break; ou para todos os items do menu vc gostaria de fazer  login novamente?

Comment: Nao, ele assim que escolher a opçao ja é pra mudar a tela (classe) correspondente. O problema agora que ao escolher a opçao ele nao entra na classe e para de executar

Comment: colocar por favor a classe cadastrar.

Comment: David aproveitando e ja pergunto como faço pra abrir esse arquivo que estou salvando nessa classe, em uma outra, so que nessa outra classe ele vai abrir o arquivo onde esta as informaçoes do paciente e somente adicionar as informaçoes referente ao exame, e assim salvar tudo. Entendeu?

Comment: o que está faltando é vc iniciar o metodo inserir colocar 
 Cadastrar cad = new Cadastrar(); cad.Inserir();Inicio();break;

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41421/discussion-between-carlos-diego-and-david-cabral).